# Area functions for the same linear function

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried understanding how to do this but its just confusing as hell. I understand the concepts of antiderivatives and integrals but this just makes no sense to me.

let $f(t) = t$ and consider the two area functions $$A(x) = \int_0^ x f(t)dt$$ and 
$$F(x) = \int_2^x f(t)dt$$ 
(someone tell me how to make these?)

a. Evaluate $A(2)$ and $A(4)$. Then use geometry to find an expression for $A(x)$ for all $x \geq 0$

b. Evaluate $F(4)$ and $F(6)$. Then use geometry to find an expression for$ A(x)$ for all $\geq 2$

c. Show that $A(x) - F(x)$ is a constant.

could someone explain how to solve these please?

Comment: actually i just figured it out

Comment: i figured out that im supposed to take the anti derivitive of t which is t^2/2 then do 2^2/2 - 0^2/2 which gives 2 as the answer now i just gotta figure out the geometry part

Comment: the expression is t^2/2 actually all these ts should be replaced with x's

Comment: For the geometry, all you need to know is that the area of a triangle is half the base times the height.

Comment: ok it looks like the expression for A(x) is x^2/2 but what i dont get is that this is a quadratic and not a triangle....

Comment: The integral from $0$ to $x$ (or from $2$ to $x$) of $t\,dt$ is a quadratic in $x$. The area of a triangle (or in the second case, a trapezoid, or triangle minus a triangle) is also a quadratic in $x$.

Comment: interesting....

Comment: It is early in the game. The problem is trying to persuade you that you can find areas using antiderivatives.

Comment: i just want to make sure my teacher doesnt throw us off on the exam...

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out after I asked.

To evaluate $A(2)$ set $f(t)$ equal to $t$. Then solve the integral by taking the anti-derivative of $x$ which is $(x^2)/2$ and plug in 2 and then $0$, find the difference. $2^2/2 - 0^2/2 = 2$. same with $A(4)$, $4^2/2 - 0^2/2 = 8$. this graph makes a quadratic, and the area is the same as a triangle, which will be $\mathrm{base \cdot height }/ 2$, which is the same as $x\cdot x/2$ when base is equal to height.